# Stuck in Flotsam

Tags: the-witcher-2

I have done everything I could in Flotsam, but it seems there is a house which I can't enter.
When I approach the door - the action to open the door shows up but also an action to light the torch lights up. However whenever I try to open the door, it lights the torch instead.

Here are some screenshots of the house, it's location on the map, and the list of my current quests: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K39MQ.jpg

Anyone had that problem?

Comment: What door are we talking about?  Could you post a screenshot or give us a hint as to where it is in the town?

Comment: Screenshots uploaded. Also, it seems there are other quests I still need to do, but I don't know how to proceed on those either, e.g. I still don't know how to get the troll drunk.

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought perhaps this was the Blue Stripe HQ, but consulting a [map of Flotsam](http://guides.gamepressure.com/thewitcher2assassinsofkings/guide.asp?ID=11326), I found that Blue Stripe HQ is somewhat to the east of where you are now.

According to the map, there's nothing there - I'm guessing this is just a building you can't actually get into.  There don't appear to be any quests related to it, although the merchant for "The Kayran: A Matter Of Price" hangs out outdoors in this general area.

Comment: I don't remember there being anything in that building as well, there are quite a few locked doors you never get to open.